# Calculation of SHA1 sum of file from partial SHA1 sums

Tags: c#, sha1

I have partial sums of a big file, as in, of every 50MB, a total of 5 sums.

I was wondering if I could recover the whole hashsum i.e. SHA1sum of the file from just the 5 sums. Is it possible? If so, how? If not, why not?

I'm trying to code something that will do this in C#.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

The reason is that there may be collisions. It is not guaranteed that two different pieces of data will always give different SHA-1 hashes. It is just highly unlikely.

This means the data that was used to generate the hash is non-deterministic, so you can never know for sure what it was, and can thus never reconstruct your original data. Which you would need to do to then be able to hash it.

Answer (score 0):

Although it isn't possible to calculate a file's SHA-1 from partial **sums**, you **can** calculate a file's SHA-1 incrementally. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982546/incremental-hashing-in-winrt-metro).