# Incremental Hashing in WinRT/Metro

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, windows-runtime

I'm porting some code that uses incremental SHA-1 heavily:

```
SHA1 hasher = HashAlgoFactory.Create<SHA1>();
hasher.Initialize();

DiskIOCallback readCallback = null; 
readCallback = delegate(bool successful) {

if (successful)
    hasher.TransformBlock(hashBuffer, 0, count, hashBuffer, 0);
    offset += count;

if (!successful || offset == endOffset)
{
    object hash = null;
    if (successful)
    {
        hasher.TransformFinalBlock(hashBuffer, 0, 0);
        hash = hasher.Hash;
    }
```

And am looking for a WinRT/Metro equivalent. I've used hasher.HashData before; is there some relatively simple way to get incremental behaviour out of HashData, or some alternative that implements the same functionality as above (in a WinRT/Metro way)? It's entirely possible I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [CryptographicHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographichash.aspx) class:

```
var hashProvider = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1);
var hasher = hashProvider.CreateHash();
```

You can append multiple increments of data:

```
hasher.Append(bytesPart.AsBuffer());
```

Once you're done, you retrieve the hash:

```
var hash = hasher.GetValueAndReset().ToArray();
```